# jdbc.SQLServerException when i tried to connect database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2012

I have class for connecting to DB from my JavaFx application

```
public class DBConnection {

public static Connection mcConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=McQueen_db;";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return connection;
}
```

}

When i tried to connect i have an exception

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
```

I check my firewall and its ok. I think that port too. Have any thoughts whats the problem?

Comment: remove the space `localhost; databaseName` -> `localhost;databaseName`

Comment: Did you configure your mssql server so that it accepts connection via jdbc (or tcp/ip)? https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.install.doc/GUID-B15AB8CF-A123-482D-8988-F73A836EE4A7.html

Answer (score 1):

try to change "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

As sometimes, your system cannot mapping localhost correctly.

refer to [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: use   netstat -a | grep 1433  or similiar command to check if the port available or not first.